# Overloading c++ template class method

Tags: c++, templates, class

Can I overload a template class function in a class that extends its specialization?

I have the following piece of code (I've tried to simplify it to the bare minimum):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class X {
 public:
  unsigned test_x() {
    return 1;
  }
};

class Y {
 public:
  unsigned test_y() {
    return 2;
  }
};

template <typename T, typename U>
class A {

 public: 

  unsigned foo(U i) {
    cout << "A" << endl;   
    return i.test_x();
  }

  unsigned bar(T i) {
    return foo(i);
  }

};

class B : public A<Y, X> {
 public:
  unsigned foo(Y i) {
    cout << "B" << endl;   
    return i.test_y();
  }
};

int  main() {

  B b = B();
  Y y = Y();
  cout << "Hello: " << b.bar(y) << endl;   
  return 0;

}
```

However the compiler produces the following error:

```
hello.cc: In member function ‘unsigned int A<T, U>::bar(T) [with T = Y, U = X]’:
hello.cc:47:   instantiated from here
hello.cc:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘A<Y, X>::foo(Y&)’
hello.cc:24: note: candidates are: unsigned int A<T, U>::foo(U) [with T = Y, U = X]
```

Basically I would like to overload the function A::foo() in its derived class B.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently what you're asking is called "static polymorphism" and it's achieved by the means of "curiously recurring template pattern":

```
template <typename Derived, typename T, typename U>
class A {
 public:

  unsigned foo(U i) {
    cout << "A" << endl;   
    return i.test_x();
  }

  unsigned bar(T i) {
    return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->foo(i);
  }

};

class B : public A<B, Y, X> {
 public:
  // Uncomment this line if you really want to overload foo
  // instead of overriding. It's optional in this specific case.
  //using A::foo; 

  unsigned foo(Y i) {
    cout << "B" << endl;   
    return i.test_y();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** My first answer was incorrect.

When you instantiate `A` with classes `Y` and `X` the call of `foo(T)` generates an error because there no proper overloaded method defined in `A`. It suffices to declare a pure virtual method of `foo(T)` in `A` and implement this method in `B`.

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class A {
public: 
  virtual unsigned foo(T i) = 0;
  unsigned foo(U i) { /* as above */ }
  unsigned bar(T i) {
    return foo(i); // calls abstract foo(T)
  }
};
/* B is left untouched */
```

Compiling this generates this output:

```
B
Hello: 2
```

Comment: -1 Misses the point of the question. OP does not want to use `A::foo` with an object of type `B` (name hiding problem), he wants to use `B::foo` in `A::bar` (base class needs to be aware of overloads in derived classes).

Comment: I do understand the point of the question. If you don't import `A::foo` into `B`'s scope `B::foo` hides `A::foo` completely. OP wants to overload `A::foo` with `B::foo` and that just works with the using declaration.

Comment: You could try it with a compiler to see if your suggestion fixes the code. The only place where `foo` is called from is `A::bar`. As far as `A` is concerned, `B` may or may not exist and the using declarations in `B` are completely irrelevant.

Comment: Much better now. However, now this change breaks `A`. To keep the behavior of A unchanged, the function probably should not be pure, but rather implemented as `virtual unsigned foo(T i) { return foo(static_cast<U>(i));}` It's starting to look that the class `A` might have been conceptually rather broken in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the overloads in derived classes cannot be used from the base class where they are to be called from.

What you can do, is to extract the `foo` method, so you can specialize it for `B.`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class X {
 public:
  unsigned test_x() {
    return 1;
  }
};

class Y {
 public:
  unsigned test_y() {
    return 2;
  }
};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct Foo
{
    unsigned foo(U i) {
    cout << "A" << endl;
    return i.test_x();
  }
};

template <typename T, typename U>
class A : public Foo<T, U> {

 public:
  unsigned bar(T i) {
    return this->foo(i);
  }
};

template <>
struct Foo<Y, X>
{
 public:
  unsigned foo(Y i) {
    cout << "B" << endl;
    return i.test_y();
  }
};

class B : public A<Y, X> {
};

int  main() {

  B b = B();
  Y y = Y();
  cout << "Hello: " << b.bar(y) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```